# Firebase Notifications are suddenly coming delayed hence Android not getting response when making API calls

Tags: android

When we are making calls to our server APIs (PHP APIs; Backend MYSQL DB) from Android; The database updates are occurring as normal, but following this the FCM notifications are coming delayed. As a result all users are seeing Error Messages on The android side as they don't receive the response in time and as a result there is a error on the Android side due to missing response

Any idea if there has been any change with Firebase causing this suddenly

Answer (score 0):

use websocket(web rtc or socket io ) i already have the same problem

Comment: But this was working very well till recently. Has anything changed in the last 3 - 5 days which has caused this service degradation.

Comment: I have been having problem with firebase about 2 year my friend and i decided to switch on socketio